# Tool to test alternative resources selection with qualifiers in Android

Tags: android, layout, qualifiers

I'm having hard time testing different layouts based on qualifiers in Android. I was wondering if anyone knows about some tool to verify what resources are picked up based on some device configuration (ex, screen size, android version ..).
Ideally I'd like to select among common predefined configurations or I'd like to specify my custom device configuration, provide my apk (or project) and have as output a sort of resolution plan telling me what has been selected and why.
Do you know if there's something like that?
Thanks

Comment: Could anyone tell me why this is not a real question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" so that I can modify it to be reopen?

Answer (score 0):

I pick a common view, then replicate it into each resource folder.  For example, in my current project, I have a title bar on the main page.  I simply hard code the text to the resource folder name e.g. res-layout-large-land, or perhaps a placeholder image with RDLL (for res-drawable-large-land) emblazoned upon it.